# Cron ran only once

Tags: cron

I'm running Ubuntu x64 14.04 and have a cron setup to run a shell script.

```
0 0 * * * sh root/delete.sh
```

It should run once a day at midnight. According to my logs, it ran once and then never ran again the next night.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: To me it looks weird that it even ran once. `sh root/delete.sh` is quite unlikely to be understood by cron. You need to indicate the full path (just guessing the paths): `/bin/sh /your/path/root/delete.sh`. You can debug it by saying `* * * * * /bin/sh/ /your/path/root/delete.sh`, since this will run every minute.

Comment: Thanks. If i do `pwd` in the directory of delete.sh, it actually is just /root so that should be fine, right?

Comment: No, you will need `/root/delete/sh` instead of `root/delete.sh` (note the leading `/`).

Comment: `* * * * * /bin/sh/ /root/delete/sh` should work correct? Still doesn't seem to be working for me :( Im putting it under `crontab -e`, is there anything else I need to be doing?

Comment: Firstly you need to check what is the path of `sh`. Do it with `which sh`. Then, use it without the trailing `/` --> `/bin/sh /root/delete.sh`

Comment: Hi thanks. My script is definitely in the root directory, and has +X permission, and runs normally when i try to use `sh delete.sh`. I'm trying to use ` * * * * * /bin/sh /root/delete.sh` but it is still not running

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but I can tell you what that command will actually (try to) do.

```
0 0 * * * sh root/delete.sh
```

Cron jobs run with the working directory set to the user's home directory.  This command will run `sh` (which resolves to `/bin/sh`) passing it the string `root/delete.sh` as an argument. `/bin/sh` will interpret that as a file name; since it doesn't start with a `/`, it's interpreted relative to the current directory.

So if you have an executable script in `$HOME/root/delete.sh`, that line should execute it every night at midnight.

For clarity, you should probably (a) use an absolute pathname, and (b) make sure the script itself has a proper `#!` line (`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`), and invoke the script directly rather than passing its name to the `sh` command. Neither of these is necessary, but they'll make your intent move obvious.

If `delete.sh` is in the `/root` directory, not under your home directory, then you should have:

```
0 0 * * * /root/delete.sh
```

If it's under `$HOME/root`, then you should have:

```
0 0 * * * $HOME/root/delete.sh
```

Again, this depends on `delete.sh` being executable (`chmod +x delete.sh`) and having a proper `#!` line at the top.

Comment: Hi thanks. My script is definitely in the root directory, and has +X permission, and runs normally when i try to use `sh delete.sh`. I'm trying to use `` * * * * * /bin/sh /root/delete.sh`` but it is still not running

Comment: Does `/bin/sh /root/delete.sh` work when you type it from the command line? Did you install the crontab using the `crontab` command?

Comment: How do you know it's not running? Does the script itself generate a log?